# Parmeter values not resolving in ADF

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a scenario where I want to dynamically pass parameters to a stored procedure. I have created a parameter called `runId` and assign the value as 1234, and created another parameter where I'm calling the `runId` parameter as:

```
{
    "PipelineRunId": {
        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.runId",
        "type": "String"
    }
}
```

But the input for the stored procedure looks like below:

```
{
    "storedProcedureName": "StoredprocName",
    "storedProcedureParameters": {
        "PipelineRunId": {
            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.runId",
            "type": "String"
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is here to see `value` as "1234", not sure if I'm making any mistake here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The value for the Stored procedure parameter `PipelineRunId` should be of expression and it is not of string type. In order to do that in stored procedure activity, do the following.

- Click `Add dynamic content` in the value text box of stored procedure parameters.
  [image]
- Enter the value `@pipeline().parameters.runId`  in the text box.
  [image]

Pipeline Json will look like below:

```
"storedProcedureParameters": {
  "PipelineRunId": {
     "value": {
               "value": "@pipeline().parameters.runId",
                "type": "Expression"
                    },
              "type": "String"
                  }
                }
```